# Algorithm for calculate intersection point of two horizontal and vertical line

Tags: java, algorithm, math

i wrote algorithm for calculate  intersection point of two line

but it works only for slope lines

i want algorithm to calculate intersection point for horizontal and vertical Lines

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Vgv.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the intersection between a horizontal and a vertical line is trivial.
Assume the horizontal line is defined by

```
y = c1
```

and the vertical line by

```
x = c2
```

(where c1 and c2 are your constants)

then the intersection is
    (c2;c1).

In the example you gave : c2 = 1 ; c1 = 6 and the intersectoin is (1;6)

Comment: will solution be different if we have to find whether line segments are intersection or not?

Comment: Yes, the solution has to be extended in that case.